# How to tell if the "clusters" I see in my pair plots are statistically significant or occurring by chance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have a data set with one row per subject. Some variables include laboratory parameters for blood chemistry, hematology, etc. I also have some flag variables: any = 1 if the subject experienced an adverse event, 0 if not; and ser_flag = 1 if the subject experienced a serious adverse event, 0 if not.

There doesn't seem to be any difference in the distribution of laboratory parameters between subjects who experienced an adverse event (any=1) and subjects who did not (any = 0). When I do a pair plot of all the lab parameters against each other and color by the any flag, there doesn't seem to be any clustering or separation of subjects.

However, when I do the same pair plot and color by ser_flag - I notice that the 20 subjects (out of roughly 2000) who experienced a serious adverse events seem to be clustered together in many of the plots.

What test (if any) can I use to determine if these clusters I think I am seeing are occurring randomly, by chance...or if they are statistically significant?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "clusters are statistically significant". For example, with respect to which null hypothesis?

Comment: You cannot make any progress on this until you can elevate your definition of "clustered" from a *psychological phenomenon* ("I notice that") to a *quantitative characteristic* of the data.  Could you provide a clear, detailed description of what a "cluster" is in you mind?

Comment: This can be done with [Hopkins Test](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/print.php?id=238)

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** Do you see what you would call "clusters" in any
of the six plots below?

[image]

Each is a sample of 200 observations from a bivariate normal
distribution. Any clusters are artifacts of random sampling.

*Addendum as requested:* (100 blue, 100 brown)

[image]

200 of each color in each plot:

[image]

Comment: Now what if we add a third variable to the plot, for example ser_ae (which takes value of 1 or 0) and have that be represented with color, and we notice that those with ser=1 are all lumped together (in different places) in every graph

Comment: Addendum with colors, just posted.